# JS: How can a child instance of a class access its parent instance of another class?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a slightly odd circumstance in my code (browser JS): An instance of a class contains an array which is used to store instances of another class. I'm not sure what's the most efficient way to store the child instances as part of the parent instance, in such a way that both the patent class can access the child classes but each child can also access the parent.

The first part is easy: Class a stores every instance of class b in a personal array (`this.my_b_instances`), it can always loop through it and find any particular b it needs to access. The second part is the tricky one: How can an instance of the b class easily gain access to that particular a class it's being stored in? I imagine I can't just set `b.parent = this_instance_of_a` as that may create a copy of a instead of referencing the original.

Here's a little mockup code showing what I want to do: It's not a very practical example, only intended to show what I need to achieve in a more complex setup. The part marked with ??? is what I don't know how to achieve, which is getting the instance of a which this instance of b is supposed to belong to.

```
class a {
    constructor() {
        this.myval = "this is my value";
        this.instances_of_b = [];
    }

    spawn_an_instance_of_b() {
        this.instances_of_b.push(new b());
    }
}

class b {
    read_myval_from_a() {
        var parent_instance_of_a = ???;
        alert(parent_instance_of_a.myval);
    }
}

var my_a = new a();
my_a.spawn_an_instance_of_b();
my_a.instances_of_b[0].read_myval_from_a();
```

Comment: Pass a reference of a when you create b? Unsure what the real world use case is.

Comment: Think of it as a stack: a{b{}}. Where there can be multiple instances of "a" each one holding its own many instances of "b". You need each a to access its b children, but also each b child to be able to access properties from the a parent they belong to.

Comment: So pass in a reference when you create b

Comment: I store a in an index too, so each b can have b.a_index then use it as a_array[this.a_index]. I wanted to know if there's a better or saner way to go about it, such as storing a permanent pointer to a directly: This feels like I'm avoiding a proper implementation.

Comment: There is no way to know that b belongs to a, you got to give it a reference.

Comment: Correct. What I was mainly uncertain about was what would pass a reference without creating a copy, so that modifying the parent would cause the child to see the updated parent rather than a copy of it stored in the child's memory on creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in a reference to your class when you make a new instance of b.

```js
class a {
  constructor() {
    this.myval = "this is my value";
    this.instances_of_b = [];
  }

  spawn_an_instance_of_b() {
    this.instances_of_b.push(new b(this));
  }
}

class b {
  constructor(parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }
  read_myval_from_a() {
    console.log(this.parent.myval);
  }
}

var my_a = new a();
my_a.spawn_an_instance_of_b();
my_a.instances_of_b[0].read_myval_from_a();
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like the right way! I wasn't sure whether doing something like this would pass a reference of a to b without duplicating a... meaning that if you make any change to a.myval, a child b trying to print that parent's myval will read the updated setting. I believe this is how instances work though, it should indeed be a reference not a copy.